# AIC rating for residential 100A main breaker

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I'm having an electrician replace my 2-unit meter main Zinsco panel with a new Siemens WP2211 panel. There will be two 100A breakers for the two units in the complex. The panel lists the following acceptable breakers:

QP, QPH, HQP, HQPH, MP-T, MP-HT.

The QP and MP-T have a 10 kA AIC, and the QPH has 22 kA and is only about $15 more than the QP. The HQP at 65 kA is three times the price and presumably overkill.

Given that this is a service entrance, I assume the amount of short-circuit current available from the utility is pretty substantial.

Is there a recommended value for residential service entrance breakers? I'm leaning toward the 22 kA QPH.

Thanks

Christian
[image]

Comment: Note that interrupting ratings are kA not kVA

Comment: I just found in the PG&E Greenbook the following section:  
********
PG&E designs its facilities so that the short-circuit duty at the service
termination will not exceed 10,000-amps symmetrical for new,
single-family, residential applicants that are supplied by an individual
service drop or lateral that is rated at 225 amps or less. This service includes
mobile homes and duplexes. 
******
So I should be fine with a 10 kA rating, although I suspect that the 22 kA rated one might be a bit more durable

Comment: That's PG&E talk for "we use super cheap service drops/laterals and rationalize it this way".  If the gov't ever figures out how much energy they are wasting heating up drop wires, they might make em fix that... Plus PG&E ownership is about to change...

Answer (score 2):

You'll have two services there.

As you say, according to PG&E, they design their facilities so that 10KA of short-circuit current is not possible for new **single family** drops. However, being a duplex with 2 meters, *you really need to ask PG&E*. It's most likely the same as the meters around you. If you're the only duplex in a single-family area that'd be different than if you're surrounded by 30-unit apartments.

Comment: Note that the PG&E statement from the Greenbook also includes "This service includes mobile homes and duplexes", so I think your statement about them doubling the capacity for a duplex is off base

Comment: It is a 200A service, but over a #2 aluminum feeder from the utility. The duplex has 2 100A breakers but one main panel with 2 meters in it. I think to PG&E it is the same kind of 200A service as a single family drop.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "durability" gain in going with the higher rating. Interrupting Capacity has ONLY to do with what happens if there is a MAJOR fault in your system. If the source (utility transformer) can deliver ***more*** than 10,000A during a fault, then breakers rated at 10kAIC might explode "with extreme prejudice" when attempting to interrupt the fault. Conversely if the utility says the available fault current is 10kA or less, breakers rated 10kAIC are fine.